# How many vehicles are there in Just Cause 2?

Tags: just-cause-2

In `Just Cause 2`, Steam version, there is an achievement called `Trying Anything Once` that says "**Drive all 104 vehicles**".

But is 104 the number of vehicles with DLC or without? What is then the total number of vehicles that you can drive in Just Cause 2 with all DLC?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

104 is the number of vehicles without DLC. As far as I can tell, there are currently six DLC vehicles available, meaning that 110 is the total number of vehicles you can drive with all DLC.